Правильно ли писать "акция в поддержку пострадавшим"?
Или строго только в поддержку пострадавших?
(а пострадавшИМ - помощь)

Наречное выражение «в поддержку» допускает два варианта трактовки: «поддержать (кого?) пострадавших (В.п.)» и «оказать поддержку (кому?) пострадавшим (Д.п.)».
Виды действий (акций) «в поддержку» имеют свойство тяготеть к одной из этих трактовок. С одной стороны: помочь, оказать услугу, проявить сочувствие к (кому?) пострадавшим (Д.п.), а с другой - обеспечить необходимым, вывезти, выручить (кого?) пострадавших (В.п.).
Поиск (в НКРЯ) выражения «в поддержку» (не только пострадавших) с анализом контекста подтверждает подавляющее преимущество трактовки в форме винительного падежа - «поддержать (кого/что?)».
Примеры редкостей в форме Д.п. (действие «в поддержку» кому?):
Не на тех напал, гнида! — неожиданно громко выкрикнул в поддержку Молодушкину самый слабый на вид из всех восьмерых — Семенов. [С. Н. Сергеев-Ценский. У края воронки (1943)]
Ну, а если это вы как бы в поддержку мне, так такого не нужно делать, потому что с таким принципом можно сильно напутать. [А. С. Макаренко. Книга для родителей (1937)]
Некая французская газета во время японской войны устроила во Франции подписку в поддержку Стесселю, его жене и прочим защитникам Порт-Артура. [А. Ф. Редигер. История моей жизни (1918)]
